# what counts as document reads in firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In Firestore, If my query only returns 10 results that match the critera, but I have to read all the 1000 documents, how much would be counted as document reads in firestore billing?

Comment: Can you share your query so it might be better to explain with that example itself?

Answer (score 0):

> If my query only returns 10 results that match the critera,

This will only cost 10 reads.

> but I have to read all the 1000 documents

If you are saying you have 1000 documents in the collection but your query returns only 10 documents, then that's 10 reads only.